# Writing hex to several microcontrollers at the same time via ICSP

Tags: microcontroller, icsp

Is it possible to write a hex code to several microcontrollers via one ICSP and one program on PC at the same time ?

More specifically : I'm looking to program 10 PICs at the same time from the same ICSP (like extending ICSP each pin with 10 wires).

Comment: Please add more information. What chip are you using? What programmer are you using? I've build programmer multiplexers and parallel programmers for this purpose.

Comment: Chip : Microchip PIC16F690
Programmer : Microchip PICKIT 3

Comment: Don't you want to read back to verify that the programming was succesfull?

Comment: FYI the term for this feature of loading firmware into multiple identical devices is "gang programmer", often found in production device programming equipment used by contract assemblers. Bigger output driver, and individual status reads for each device. Not so useful during prototype development, but gives improved assembly throughput in production.

Answer (score 5):

It is "possible", but not a good idea.

The Microchip PIC programming interface is synchronous serial with the programmer controlling the clock.  Strictly writing data to a PIC can be done to multiple PICs in parallel because each PIC only looks at the clock and data lines.

However, proper overall "programming" requires reading information back from the PIC.  This can't be done with multiple PICs in parallel.  During readback, the PIC drives the PGD line actively both high and low.  Two PICs sending back different data would cause a collision.  This could even damage either or both PICs.

Readback is important to verify that the right PIC is out there, and that the data has been correctly programmed.  Good programmers will also check the Vdd level to make sure it's within spec for the programming operation.  It could be lower than intended due to the circuit drawing more power than the programmer can provide, for example.

To program multiple PICs at the same time from a single PC, use multiple programmers.  I know some customers use multiple of my [USBProg2](http://www.embedinc.com/products/usbprog2) in exactly this application.  Multiple instances of the PIC_PROG program can be run simultaneously, and each instance can be directed to connect to a particular programmer by name.  By default, each programmer has a unique name based on its serial number.

Also, the PicKit3 is not a production programmer.  It is aimed at hobbyists and optimized for low cost.  Since you're asking about programming multiple PICs in parallel, you're in a production environment.  The cost of just one problem will outweigh any savings by cutting corners on the programmers.

If you ever have this need with one of the newer 3.3 V PICs that can enter programming mode using a special signature instead of raising MCLR to a high voltage, you can use my [LProg](http://www.embedinc.com/products/lprog) programmers.  These are small and cheap, and are production programmers, but a little slower than the USBProg2.  The PICs it supports include all the 16F1xxx parts, and many others.

Comment: There are other commercial options too, like the CCS Prime8, which allow you to program up to 8 devices with a single programmer.